# How to bind data to html table tds

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, data-binding, html-table

I have HTML Table with 10 rows how I can bind data to the tds?

I have groups where is 10 users and table with 10 rows.

Here Is my html table. I want to insert for example John into first Steve into 5 and so on.
I have this data in SQL server.

[image]

Comment: Please don't add stuff like " asp.net c#" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way..

```
<table>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("UserName") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        -
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("Email") %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
```